# AJAX is not working when add multiple items

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a cart, where I can add or remove items. I'm using sessions for cart and AJAX to add/remove products without refreshing the page. It works correctly, when one item in cart, but it shows only a request status on new page and I need to refresh it if I want to see changes. It is working fine, when only one product is in cart, otherwise I need to refresh the page.

cart.html

```
<div class="quantity__row">
    <form action="{% url 'remove_cart' %}" method="post" id="removeCartID">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ item.product.id }}" id="productRemoveID">
        <input type="submit" value="-" class="quantity__number-minus"> 
    </form>
                                                
    <input type="number" min="1" value={{ item.quantity }} readonly="readonly" class="quantity__input" id="quantityID"/>
                                                
     <form action="{% url 'add_cart' %}" method="post" id="addCartID">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ item.product.id }}" id="productAddCartID">
        <input type="submit" value="+" class="quantity__number-plus"> 
     </form>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=int(product_id)-1)
        cart = Cart(request)
        
        cart.add(product=product)
        cart_quantity = cart.get_total_len()
        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'cart_quantity': cart_quantity})

def cart_remove(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=int(product_id))
        cart = Cart(request)
        
        cart.remove(product) 
    cart_quantity = cart.get_total_len()
    return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'cart_quantity': cart_quantity})
```

scripts.js

```
$(function() {
    $('#addCartID').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url "add_cart" %}',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                product_id: $('#productAddCartID').val(),
                product_quantity: $('#quantityID').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $('#quantityID').val(response.cart_quantity); 
                $('#modal__content').html('<p>Товар добавлен в корзину</p>').show();         
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
     });
  });
});

$(function() {
    $('#removeCartID').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "remove_cart" %}',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            product_id: $('#productRemoveID').val(),
            product_quantity: $('#quantityID').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $('#quantityID').val(response.cart_quantity); 
                $('#modal__content').html('<p>Товар убран из корзины!</p>').show();         
            } else {
                $('#modal__content').html('<p>' + response + '</p>').show();
              }
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ?? Your script makes no attempt to deal with multiple products, as far as I can tell. There's one input with one value.

Comment: @Pointy These inputs are generated inside the {% for item in cart %}

Comment: OK, well it's required that the `id` of an element in the page be unique; you cannot use the same `id` value more than once, in other words.

Comment: @Pointy Ok, I got you. And do I need to use `.each()` in AJAX to enter in every form on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution. The idea was to receive a unique id of elements and getting the exact form, where the `event` happens. I added `$(this)` and I'm getting unique id. Also I need to add a check to :

**ajax.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('.addCartClass').on('submit', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
            let product_id = $(this).find('[name="product_id"]').attr('id').split('_')[1];
            $.ajax({
                url: '/add-certain-amount/',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    product_id: product_id,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        let value = $('#quantityID_' + product_id).text();
                        $('#quantityID_' + product_id).text(Number(value) + 1);
                        let amount = $('#productAmount_' + product_id).text().split(' ')[0];
                        $('#productAmount_' + product_id).text(Number(amount) + 1 + ' шт.');         
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }
            });     
        });
    });
        
$(function() {
    $('.removeCartClass').on('submit', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        let product_id = $(this).find('[name="product_id"]').attr('id').split('_')[1];
         $.ajax({
             url: '/remove/',
             type: 'post',
             data: {
                 product_id: product_id,
                 csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
             },
             success: function (response) {
                 if (response.success) {
                     let value = $('#quantityID_' + product_id).text();
                     $('#quantityID_' + product_id).text(Number(value) - 1);
                     let amount = $('#productAmount_' + product_id).text().split(' ')[0];
                      $('#productAmount_' + product_id).text(Number(amount) - 1 + ' шт.');      
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }
            });     
        });
    });
```

**views.py**

```
def add_certain_amount(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        cart = Cart(request)
        cart.add(product=product)
        cart_quantity = cart.get_total_len()
        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'cart_quantity': cart_quantity})

def cart_remove(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=int(product_id))
        cart = Cart(request)
        cart.remove(product) 
        cart_quantity = cart.get_total_len()
        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'cart_quantity': cart_quantity})
```

**base.html**

```
<div class="quantity__row">
    <form action="{% url 'remove_cart' %}" method="post" class="removeCartClass">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ item.product.id }}" id="remove_{{item.product.id}}">
        <input type="submit" value="-" class="quantity__number-minus"> 
    </form>
                                                                                        
    <span class="quantity__input" id="quantityID_{{item.product.id}}">{{ item.quantity }}</span>
                                                                                        
    <form action="{% url 'add_certain' %}" method="post" class="addCartClass">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
        {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ item.product.id }}" id="add_{{item.product.id}}">
        <input type="submit" value="+" class="quantity__number-plus"> 
    </form>
</div>
```